Feynman claimed "The ear is not very sensitive to the relative phases of the harmonics." Is that true?
In The Feynman Lectures on Physics, Dr. Richard Feynman claimed that the ear (I assume he meant the human ear) is not sensitive to the relative phases of harmonics.
However, I was asked to test electronic filters with a Textronix Vista tester using an impulse which is a pulse that is infinitely narrow, and of course is limited in its peak voltage by the filter's maximum input voltage. While an impulse does contain all harmonics at the same amplitude as the fundamental, making it perfect for testing a filter, the impulse, being very narrow contains virtually no energy, so the amplitudes of everything from the fundamental to the thousandth harmonic are very, very small in amplitude and any noise in the system overwhelms the signal making it impossible to get a stable and consistent reading of the filer's cutoff frequency.
I took the spectrum of an impulse, randomized the phases of all harmonics, performed an inverse FFT and normalized the time domain wave to fit the filter's maximum input voltage. This technique worked wonderfully and gave me stable, repeatable results. I published this technique on using white noise to test a filter.
Because white noise is spectrally identical to an impulse, but the phases of the harmonics are different, this seems to prove Feynman's statement on the phases of harmonics wrong. Did I outsmart Feynman?

At what point in your experiment was your ear involved?

I seem to remember that the auditory faculty is sensitive to transient shape, which phase shifts heavily influence, and that the cited statement holds only for steady-state tones. It is also a nonlinear channel, so peak amplitude matters. If your concern is really the ear you might re-ask with that slant on Music.SE or perhaps Biology.SE.

Or also on DSP.SE where some music technologists hang out.

"At what point in your experiment was your ear involved?" I used automated test instruments to do the test, but I know that the sound of an impulse, such as a gunshot, is audibly different from the sound of white noise. I devised a way to test that assumption by writing a PERL script that converts an Excel .CSV file to a .WAV file that can be played on a PC. The link to this PERL script is here:http://www.danbullard.com/dan/images/cnvrt_2_wav.pl.zip

"Because white noise is spectrally identical to an impulse, but the phases of the harmonics are different, this seems to prove Feynman's statement on the phases of harmonics wrong." You seem to be missing the fact that there are many other components to sound besides spectrum and relative phases of components. Surely you're aware of many, many reasons why an impulse would sound different to humans from white noise that have nothing to do with the relative phases of the components.

" there are many other components to sound besides spectrum and relative phases of components." Name them. Fourier didn't, are you claiming to be smarter than Fourier?

You could try asking Alan Bullard.

"Did I outsmart Feynman?" No. You've done the opposite.

What Feynman means by that statement is that the "ear" (cochlea) is a spectrum analyzer with a large set of very narrow band filters each followed by a square law (energy) detector, that is all. You can test if Feynman is correct in saying that the phase has no importance by having two tones of equal frequency and amplitude, one on the left ear and one on the right ear simultaneously, meanwhile varying the relative phase between them. Experiments have shown that the brain cannot tell their relative phase variation.
Then how does a human tell the direction of the wavefront, ie., direction from which the sound originates? By measuring a time difference of arrival between the two ears. Radar/sonar prefer phase measurements when is available because it is more accurate in white additive normal thermal noise. But in a complicated multipath environment (echo) such as almost all ground acoustic environments are the real life performance between phase coherent and time difference of arrival (TDA)* measurements can actually prefer the much simpler TDA unless rather complicated interference removal algorithms are employed in the phase difference measurement.
The same indifference to phase happens when measuring on one ear one frequency and on the other a harmonic of the same frequency. The brain cannot discern the phase of one relative to the other although the relative phase between them is meaningful for they are coherent signals. This is because both are detected noncoherently.


TDA of PDA because the ears are spatially separated by the skull therefore both the relative phase and the relative arrival time depend on the direction of the acoustic wavefront.


It's worth noting that the ability of humans to perceive binaural beats suggests that there's a bit more to the story, and that some phase information must reach the brain (or be somehow reconstructed in the brain). I'm not very familiar with actual research on this topic, however, and it's quite hard to google for with all the associated pseudoscience out there. :/

@IlmariKaronen you may be right about that, I surely have not kept up with the auditory physiological developments. My answer was to explain what Feynman might have meant by his comment. I learned a little about these things when I worked on RF-DOA problems and learned that a female cricket with a ~2mm separation of ears or so can find her love of life in the grass; how does she do that?

Regarding the last (real) paragraph, I don't think you need one frequency in each ear. You can just play two harmonizing frequencies at the same time, then play it again with a different phase shift between them. Or have the phase difference shift continuously (at, say, a half revolution per second) (which I think ultimately amounts to slightly tweaking the frequency of one of the waves), and note that you cannot tell that the waveform evolves.

Speculation, not fact. Test my statement using real instruments. I used a Nextest Lightning to do this because the Tektronix Vista was not up to the task. An Applicos would work too, but speculation does not prove anything, I PROVED my statements in the article with a real insturment.

@IlmariKaronen From this answer: "You can test if Feynman is correct in saying that the phase has no importance by having two tones of equal frequency and amplitude". From the binaural beats article: "A binaural beat is an auditory illusion perceived when two different pure-tone sine waves, with a less-than 40 Hz or so difference between them". The binaural beats article assumed it would be obvious that tones with the same frequency would not create audible beating because beat frequencies only arise when the two tones differ in frequency, not phase.

Indeed, I have speculated on what Feynman might have meant. As regards to whether the human ear is or is not sensitive to phase I stand by the experiment I described. In your question you detailed how one might generate a flat spectrum. Contrary to your claim that an impulse is spectrally the same as a white noise, an impulse has no power spectrum while the white noise has a power spectrum. The former is not random, the latter is; moreover, there is no mathematical scheme by which the power of an impulse is definable. I have no idea what you proved in your article for that is not accessible.

I had "learned" at some point that time and amplitude differences are how we locate high-frequency sounds, but that phase differences are how we locate long-wanelength sounds. "Arrival time" spans several oscillations, and suddenly "turning on" a low-frequency sound requires mixing in high-frequency components. Your argument here suggests that continuous long-wavelength sounds, or sounds which have gone through a low-pass filter (like the thumping from the dance club down the street) can't be located. I'm not sure that's my experience.

@rob I am not now nor have I ever claimed that long wavelength sounds cannot be located, after all seismologists do this as a living. All I said was that  phase measurement based localization in which I have some personal experience, not acoustic but RF, is a difficult business, the more severe the multipath environment the more difficult it is, and it must also be accompanied by a rather sophisticated algorithm to resolve such interference. This is why airplanes, especially the naval planes, try to fly at as low an altitude as possible;

and it is not because the curvature of the earth but because the simultaneous reception of the line of sight echo and the one reflected off the earth is very difficult to separate, and this is only one reflector.

Sorry for the imprecision. I was trying to say that, without phase sensitivity, it's not obvious how human listeners would be able to locate long-wavelength sounds. Seismologists generally accomplish this by having multiple seismometers separated by more than the wavelengths of the sounds. As for "sophisticated algorithms," this is for the brain to do. My recollection (from 2004-ish) is that there is a head-size-based wavelength gap where neither arrival time nor phase difference is very good at locating a sound, and that animals with predator-alarm calls tend to use frequencies in this gap.

'By measuring a time difference of arrival between the two ears. '
This is not true. Just play with the balance of your home or car stereo. You know where the sound is from from its relative intensity in both ears.

@my2cts THAT is time difference of arrival measurement

@hyportnex You’ve got to be joking.

My article is not accessible? Try this link: https://www.electronicdesign.com/home/article/21200840/its-all-in-the-noise

It is easy enough to LISTEN to the answer. Use Excel to create 2047 zeros, with a single one added to make 2048 samples. Do an FFT on this wave (Excel can do FFTs, look it up) and use standard math to convert the complex result to magnitude and phase. Do the same with 2048 random numbers (Excel has a random number generator). Note the magnitude and phase of both waves. Save both waves to CSV. Then use my Perl script (https://www.danbullard.com/dan/images/cnvrt_2_wav.pl.zip) to convert the waves to WAV files and listen to them on your computer.

No. You just found a special case where the relatives phases of all the harmonics adds up into such a big difference in the waveform that you actually can hear it. I expect it works if the fundamental frequency is low enough for you to hear individual clicks with silence in between. At higher fundamental frequencies, you would not be able to distinguish delta functions from white noise, unless the impulses were loud enough to damage your eardrum.
Hearing works by different frequencies stimulating different receptors in the ear. You hear a pitch if a receptor is stimulated, regardless of phase.

"I expect..." That is pure speculation, prove what you say. And changing the amplitude of the fundamental as you suggest, does not fit this case. I never touched the amplitudes of the fundamental or the harmonics, yet you can hear the difference between an impulse and white noise.

Interesting. I can only speculate as to why you hear differences. Is the power in the two signals the same? If so, it is concentrated in very high power impulses in one train. Perhaps there is clipping in the speakers? If you put a microphone in front of the speakers and use a spectrum analyzer, do you get the same power spectrum for the two cases?

"I can only speculate as to why you hear differences" I can only speculate why you can't admit that the sound of a gun being fired and rain falling on the roof make distinctly different sounds.

The way hearing works is that acoustic vibrations that reach you inner ear cause mechanical vibrations of the so-called hair cells inside cochlea. Different hair cells happen to have different sizes and hence different natural vibration frequencies. as a result they only respond to a narrow frequency range of external vibrations near corresponding resonant frequencies (the Q-factors of hair cells must be reasonable). What each such cell then transmits to the brain is the amplitude of its vibration. So in essence the ear works as a spectrum analyzer, but what reaches the brain is the intensity of each harmonic, not its phase. To summarize, what Feynman says here sounds right to me.

We can show his claim to be false even more simply: imagine one drummer drumming at 60 bpm, and another drumming at 120 bpm. Would the human ear be insensitive to their relative phases? Of course not! So clearly Feynman's claim is true only for sufficiently high frequencies. How much is "sufficiently high"? Somewhere in the neighborhood of 20 Hz. Below that, periodic signals are perceived as beats, and above that, they are perceived as tones. The human ear is sensitive to difference in beat phases, but not in tone phases.
As for your reference to the "fundamental frequency", I'm unclear what that's referring to. If we're talking about a theoretical ideal impulse, being infinitely narrow in the time domain means being infinitely wide in the frequency domain, so how can there be a finite fundamental frequency?
Of course, a true impulse is physically impossible; the infinite narrowness marks it as nonphysical. What's not as obvious is that true white noise is also impossible; as you note, white noise has the same spectrum as an impulse, so its spectrum is also infinite. So if you have one signal somehow approximating an impulse, and another approximating white noise, that raises the question of just what you consider to be "close enough" to the theoretical ideal for it to bring Feynman's claim into question, and what bandwidth your approximations have. If you're dealing with less than 20 Hz, then we're into beat frequency, and if it's higher than 20 Hz, then it must last less than 100 ms.

"As for your reference to the "fundamental frequency", I'm unclear what that's referring to. " The fundamental frequency of an impulse depends on how long you sample. If I sample an impulse at 1MHZ and take 4096 samples, then 1 cycle yields a Fourier Frequency of 244.140625Hz, that makes the fundamental frequency 244.140625Hz, the 2nd harmonic is 488.28125Hz, the 3rd harmonic is 732.421875Hz and so on. The amplitude of every harmonic will be identical, which WOULD make the impulse perfect for testing filters, but the amplitude of each harmonic is only 488uV, which will be crushed by any noise.

There is a mathematical catch in the example of white noise and impulse. The two are spectrally identical only when considered as infinite signals in time. Human ears clearly analyze sounds only locally in time: they are not really mathematically perfect spectrum analyzers, which you can model using the Fourier transform. They are like real-world spectrum analyzers, so they measure things locally in time: the mathematical analogue of the Fourier transform in this case is the FBI transform, which multiplies the signal by a Gaussian cutoff localized in time before measuring the frequencies.
The point is that the Fourier transform of white noise and impulses are identical in absolute value, but their FBI transforms are not :)
That is why human ears can tell the difference between the two. They are real-world spectral analyzers, not mathematically perfect ones. Whether this '''''proves''''' Feynmann wrong or not it's a matter of interpretation (I personally don't fully understand his sentence). What I want to underline is that one should be very careful when talking about frequencies and spectrum: real-world applications want to measure spectral information only locally in time, but if you think of spectra mathematically, they only make sense when you look at signals that are defined for all times.

So the spectrum of an impulse and the spectrum of white noise IS admittedly identical,  and the human ear CAN tell the difference but despite Feynman saying that the ear is not very sensitive to the one thing that differentiates the two, he wasn't wrong. Got it. When someone says something that is provably false, it doesn't prove they were wrong. Sound like Flat Earth thinking to me.

A statement is provably false if it is stated objectively. "Is not very sensitive" coud mean a lot of things depending on the context. That is why I say I don't fully understand his sentence, I would need more context.

Then buy Feynman's books and buy my books, read them. That will give you plenty of context.

I don't need mathematical or physical context from other sources. I would need more context concerning the specific sentence (the precise paragraph from the lectures, etc...) to understand what he meant by that. Why don't you just provide context yourself, if you want to know what people think about your ideas? Also, sorry to disagree, but what you are doing is publishing a post online, citing sentences from other sources completely out of context, and accusing people of flat-earth thinking when raising doubts and asking for more context... Who is the flat-earther here again?

I posted a very specific answer and the "powers that be" deleted it, it's pointless for me to expound on this topic, they will just delete my words. Watch my videos, read my books or read my articles on LinkedIn https://www.linkedin.com/in/dan-bullard-8213046/recent-activity/articles/

Your question is a very long-winded way to present the following simple idea: "if the human ear does not distinguish between two waveforms whose spectral compositions are identical, but whose components' phases differ, then why does white noise sound different from an impulse?"
This is actually quite an interesting question. I cannot comment on Feynman's original intent, but it is very well established that altering the relative phase between two audible sounds and listening to their superposition will lead to dramatically different results for different relative phase offsets.
I present two examples: one mathematical and one pratical.

Consider a single sine wave. If I were to duplicate it and listen to the superposition of the duplicate with the original, then I would hear a louder sine wave. If I were to shift the phase by 180°, I would hear nothing. Thus, I am sensitive to the relative phase.
While recording music in professional studios, a significant challenge is to ensure that when you record an instrument with two microphones, both microphones are equidistant from the source, and are thus "in-phase." Should the differences be unequal, there will be destructive interference between the two microphones' signals if you listen to them simultaneously, which has a distinctly noticeable weak sound, and often a kind of artificial "swirling" sensation too.


I would, however, strongly encourage you to be respectful, both to people here and to scientists of the past who cannot respond to defend their opinions. Asserting that someone is wrong does not mean you "outsmarted" them. If someone in the comments claims they disagree with someone else, they are not claiming to be "smarter." This is the internet and we're just here to learn and have fun, not to assert superiority and gain fame. There's no need to speculate about whether people who reply are speaking from experience, or to suggest that they don't know about FFTs. Tell them which part of their argument you disagree with, or move on.

"Consider a single sine wave" The question is NOT about single sine waves, it's about HARMONICS. It's obvious from several examples what you are saying is true, noise cancelling headsets for example, flip the phase of incoming sound to cancel it out. But this question is about harmonics, can the ear hear the difference between a gunshot (impulse) and rain (white noise), which share the exact same spectrum (flat from DC to Fmax) but differ in the phase relationship to the fundamental, the lowest frequency in the spectrum. The impulse harmonics are all cosine waves, white noise have random phase

Let's focus on just one ear because with two ears things get much more intricate. Let's take a waveform having a frequency e.g. 500Hz, and a waveform having a multiple of it e.g. 1000Hz. By creating by computer these waveforms you may shift the phase highest frequency from e.g. 0 to 360 degrees.By testing it if you feel the same sound when the phase is shifted than the assumption is true, if these are different sounds the assumption is false.
I indicate to use submultiple frequencies, because if frequencies are non exact ratios, then the reasoning is different. TO BE NOTED THAT if superimposed frequencies are very near, then when they are in phase you hear loud, when when they are in opposite phase then you don't hear anything (supposing to have them of the same amplitude). So if the phase shift is so small you may hear for a very long time a very loud sound at the common frequency but that sound is modulated by another frequency as these fell slowly out of synchronization up to arriving to total silence where one cancels out the other. So generally speaking the statement is theoretically wrong as the phase shift in that case may be detected (but at out of sound bands). For sub multiple frequencies it may by true under experimental proof!!! ( I suppose it is true -- but I haven experimented yet ) , BUT YOU MAY JUST HIT TWO notes on the piano, at once ( it is never at once any way so phases will be out of phase but these will also be not exactly multiples) if you hear every time the same sound then the statement is practically true !!!!!! I actually don't have a piano at hand, but musicians do not change music when hitting one note 0.00001 second before the other note !!!!!! so we may assume from third party experience that it is true !!!
The previous phrase seems to be wrong after experimental test.
I used the site
https://meettechniek.info/additional/additive-synthesis.html
and created a sound with a frequency and it's second degree harmonic, by changing the relative phase it seems to my hear that something is detected.
BUT PAY ATTENTION if frequencies are not exactly submultiples (as e.g. in the piano) there is no phase shift as that is continuous, and thus the difference cannot be detected.
Please check with your ear and revert back !!!

The thing about the piano is wrong (pianos are complex physical systems). Everything before that seems reasonable to me.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It is not an unclear answer, it is just plain wrong and proves nothing of the sort  claimed because, eg.,  when you have two tones $\pi$ phase apart then the ear receives $0$ as in zero. In general, when you receive something like $\sum_k A_k cos(\omega t+\phi_k)$ for an arbitrary set of phases $\phi_k$ and amplitudes $A_k$ all at the exact frequency $\omega$ that sum is just some $Acos (\omega t +\phi)$ from elementary trigonometry, that is a single tone at the same frequency with some other phase and amplitude.

@hyportnex It is not plain wrong, as when you have two tones with a common submultiple, than you are able to speak about phases if not you are unable. So let's take 1000Hz and add to it 500Hz at the same volume level. Let's start them in phase, and let's start them 180 degrees apart ( measuring degrees on the 1000Hz waveform) then neither sound clears the other one, as it is obvious that sin(2π1000t/s)+sin(2π500t/s) and sin(2π1000t/s)+sin(2π500t/s+π) [where t is time measured in seconds and s is second] are both <>0(t) .

Feynman is talking about "harmonics" in that sentence. "Harmonics" is used in the context of periodic signals. Concerning periodic signals, the human ear has a frequency range that goes from 20Hz to 20.000Hz.
If you really wanted to disprove what Feynmann is saying, you should consider a periodic pulse signal of frequency that sits comfortably between 20Hz and 20.000Hz and compare it with a periodic white noise. And clearly you want the two signals to have the same volume, so you would have to run the periodic pulse on a device with a large voltage output so that the pulses are as close as possible to ideal ones.
If you did the above experiment and found a clear difference between the two sounds, maybe you would convince me.

"the human ear has a frequency resolution that goes from 20Hz to 20.000Hz." Resolution is different from range. The human ear has a RANGE of 20Hz to 20,000Hz, but resolution is AT LEAST 1/12th of an octave within that range. We know this because we have this thing called music, and many (not all) people have Perfect Pitch, they can hear and sing to a resolution of 1/12th of an octave,

I meant "range" of course, not resolution. Now corrected. So, what do you think about my answer?

Your answer is gibberish. Have you ever done an FFT? I have done millions of them, literally. My code is still run all over the world millions of times a day for the last 30 years. You are just speculating, which is all the people on this site do.

A video containing two identical sounds, identical spectrally, but not in the phases of the spectra, proving that humans can hear the relative phases of harmonics.
